# Parsing multidimensional array input from html to php via jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

I have a problem sending html inputs to php via ajax..I have multiple input fields like so:

```
<input type="text" name="fields[]['name']" >
```

Then i send those to php via jquery ajax like so: `$.post('test.php',$('#form').serialize,function(data){alert(data)});`

In test php i print fields like so `print_r($_POST['fields'])`.

I was hoping for a key=>value multidimensional array but what i get instead is an array like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 102
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Seo Offsite
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
        )
```

What is the problem ? How can i get the values like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['id'] => 102
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['name'] => Seo Offsite
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['code'] => 0
        )
```

Comment: try and remove the ' in the input, like so: `<input type="text" name="fields[][name]" >`

Comment: That works in showing with print_r the array, but how can i iterate through it with php ? foreach $fields as $field and then $field['name'] or $field[name] is not working :(

Comment: The issue is that with the way it's done is that for each time you run through the array, the two other 'key names' will not exist, meaning, First run. id will be there but name and code will not, (and so on). So you could do a `echo isset($field['name']) ?  $field['name'] : NULL; ` and then add that line for the other fields aswell. (replaced the name with id and code (and so on))

Comment: Just a suggestion, You should avoid putting blank array in between for eg. MYDATA [][name] . It should always  be at last location MYDATA[name][]. Its solves out looping problem

Comment: Try as `<input type="text" name="fields[name][]" >`

Comment: if `<input type="text" name="fields[name][]" >` and `<input type="text" name="fields[id][]" >` you'll get values on your page as like `[name] => array( [0] => whatever [1] => some) [id] => array ([0] =>1 [1] =>2)`

Answer (score 1):

In  earlier developments I solved this topic by managing the field index in the client side for example.

```
<input type="text" name="fields[0]['name']" >
<input type="text" name="fields[0]['id']" >


<input type="text" name="fields[1]['name']" >
<input type="text" name="fields[1]['id']" >
...
```

And I usually use .serializeArray() instead .serialize